# How to build automatic divide the column value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some dataframe which have different ncol. I want to replace the value by the certain rule which is from the second column the value in this column should be the original one divide the value before it. For example:

```
df= data.frame(rep(60,3),c(40:42),c(30:32),c(1:3))
colnames(df) <- c(1,2,3,4)
> df
  1  2  3  4
1 60 40 30 1
2 60 41 31 2
3 60 42 32 3
#rule:all the first column should divide 100, the second col divide first col
#     the third col divide second col and so on.
#ideal result 
  1    2      3     4 
1 0.6 0.667 0.75  0.033
2 0.6 0.683 0.756 0.065 
3 0.6 0.7   0.762 0.094
#the only idea I got now is that use Map and manual replace it
u1<-df$'1'/100
u2<-Map("/",df$`2`,df$`1`)
...
allu <- dataframe(u1,u2,...)
```

Is that any possibility to do this automatically with different ncol? Thank you in advance : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by removing the first column (`df[-1]`) and last column (`df[-ncol(df)]`), divide it so that we are dividing alternate columns, and `cbind` with the first column divided by 100

```
cbind(df[1]/100, df[-1]/df[-ncol(df)])
#    1         2         3          4
#1 0.6 0.6666667 0.7500000 0.03333333
#2 0.6 0.6833333 0.7560976 0.06451613
#3 0.6 0.7000000 0.7619048 0.09375000
```

Comment: Wow super, your answer works! Thank you! But I still do not get the point that how df[-1]/df[-length(df)] works? Is that df/df means to divide the values col by col?

Comment: @Codezy When you do `df[-1]`, you have 3 colums where the first column is the 2nd column from the original dataset, similarly with `df[-ncol(df)]`, you have the first column remains the same, but we are removing the last column so that the dimensions are equal for dividing.